# How to add pass.pkpass file into pass wallet app in android without open wallet app

Tags: android, wallet

I used below code for adding 'pass.pkpass' file into wallet pass application

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent .setType("application/pkpass");
intent .setPackage("io.walletpasses.android");
intent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(uri));
((Activity) applicationContext).startActivityForResult(intent , 1);
```

It is adding successfully in wallet app But i want to add pkpass file into wallet without open wallet app ,means only click to add pass and show a message that your pass have successfully added.If I want to show pass then goto wallet app.is it possible or not .
Refrence Link :  https://walletpasses.io/developer/

Comment: It is up to the developer how they choose to handle intents.  Better to contact them directly.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your inspiration for "application/pkpass" - AFAIK pkpass always has a vendor prefix

Comment: application/pkpass : 
pkpass is generally file extention name in 'application/pkpass' an other word we can say that it is file formate.
Exp: .html-> text/html
     .mpeg-> audio/wav
     .pdf -> application/pdf
     .apk -> application/vnd.android.package-archive